# Julia Dates: Last Day of Previous Month

Tags: date, julia

I'm working in Julia with DataFrames, and want to filter some Date and DateTime columns. To do that I need the last day of the month previous to month of whenever a data job is run.

For example, if today's date is `Date("2021-07-21")`, I'd like to obtain `2021-06-30`.

I do this in Redshift SQL all the time, which looks like this:

```sql
select last_day(current_date - interval '1 month');
┌────────────┐
│  last_day  │
├────────────┤
│ 2021-06-30 │
└────────────┘
```

Answer (score 5):

Before I remembered to check the [Julia standard library Dates](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Dates/), I found some web tutorial that only mentioned the date `floor/ceil` functions:

```
using Dates

julia> floor(today(), Month) - Day(1)
2021-06-30

julia> typeof(ans)
Date

julia> floor(now(),Month) - Day(1)
2021-06-30T00:00:00
```

This works fine and I don't see how it could fail. However, the always excellent Julia docs describe the dedicated functions for this.

```
julia> lastdayofmonth(today() - Month(1))
2021-06-30

# maybe a leap year would cause a problem
julia> lastdayofmonth(Date("20200331","yyyymmdd") - Month(1))
2020-02-29

julia> lastdayofmonth(Date("20200229","yyyymmdd") + Month(1))
2020-03-31
```

There are many useful functions like `firstdayofmonth()`, `dayofweek()`, `isleapyear()`.  Looks like everything is in order!

##### Edit: date arithmetic should be inside the function

Corrected the following error, I subtracted the month after finding the last day, works in postgres but not Julia Dates:

```
# WRONG, works only if prior month is shorter
lastdayofmonth(today()) - Month(1)

lastdayofmonth(Date("20210228", "yyyymmdd")) - Month(1)
2021-01-28
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `lastdayofmonth(today() - Month(1))`?  Notice the parenthesis at the end. See the result of, for example, `lastdayofmonth(Date("20200624", "yyyymmdd")) - Month(1)`

Comment: ah! Thank you @hckr you are right again. Editing solution.